# Manage Google Apps without being a user

Tags: google-workspace

I have a client who I am going to setup a free Google Apps account. I know with the free account the client is limited to 10 users. Is there a way that I can manage their Google Apps account *without* being an user or taking an user space.

*EDIT*

Google Apps for free is no longer avalaible as of 12/6/12 See [Here](http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en-us&answer=2855120) for more info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see how that could be possible:  the domain-administrator needs to be one of the users.

Also, are you sure it's still 10 users for free?   I know it used to be, but thought that it got reduced to three.

Comment: its upto 10 users for free - checked it recently.

Comment: Google Apps for free is no longer available as of 12/6/12 See [Here](http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en-us&answer=2855120) for more info.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest setting up a single user account that you know will always be needed, no matter what users come and go.  Webmaster@ or administrator@ or something like that.

Otherwise, you will need to share a log in with one of the active users setup as super admin.  So far, I have found no way to admin a domain without being a user account in that domain.